# How to stop support for ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My game is build specifically for iPhone and not larger screens like iPad retina. In Xcode, how do I stop my app from being considered as an iPad game.

I tried choosing iPhone under deployment info section in Xcode, but it didn't help.

Any help pls.

Here is the Xcode screenshot

[image]

I have also set the Target Device Family as iPhone

[image]

Comment: I see "MainInterface" of your project settings is blank. Do you have a storyboard or xib in that project at all?

Comment: No. Its an old game. Not using xib. All screen objects are being created using code. I am using cocos2d. Need to drop support for iPad

Comment: You cannot prevent an iPhone application running in expanded or iPhone resolution on an iPad - is this what you are seeing or is the application launching as a full iPad app?

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't understand your question completely. The game is build for iphone in the sense that spacing of buttons and size of images is for iphone. But since no restriction has been set in Xcode, anyone can run it on iPad also. When I submitted the game to App Store, apple rejected saying that the UI is too crowded on iPad.

Comment: There are two ways that an app can operate on iPad - If it is an iPhone only app then it will display as an iPhone sized "window" in the middle of the screen, with an option to "enlarge" by pressing the 2x button - still at iPhone resolution but everything doubled - iOS can detect it as a Universal app and launch it with full iPad resolution - normally you would use either an iPad specific storyboard or xib file, or handle the resolution in code.  From Apple's comment it seems that second case applies here but your code doesn't layout correctly

Comment: From the settings in your screenshot, it is an iPhone only application so it should get displayed as the small window/2x iPhone style app.  There is a known issue where specifying a launch image storyboard will cause iPhone only applications to launch at iPad resolution on iPads, but you haven't shown that part of your project settings

Comment: yes I see 1x and 2X buttons in bottom right corner when i run the game on iPad. Shall I resubmit again to apple with some comments or I should do some settings change in Xcode. I don't want Apple to test this game on iPad because it is not built for that screen size. Neither do I want this game to be listed in iPad game category on app store.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63830/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sandeep).

Comment: You don't have to change any settings nor have to submit again. It is an iPhone only application already, and Apple won't test it on iPad. And It's not going to be listed in iPad games category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involves
1) In Xcode, under Build Settings->Targeted Device Family->Choose iPhone
2) Check that when you run the app on iPad it shows 1x/2x in bottom right corner

If apple rejects the app, tell them it is not built for iPad.